# Different accuracies on different machines using same seeds, code and dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to develop a CNN for signature recognition to identify which person a given signature belongs to. There are 3 different classes(persons) and 23 signatures for each of them. Having this little amount of samples, I decided to use the Keras `ImageDataGenerator` to create additional images.

However, testing the CNN on different machines (Windows 10 and Mac OS) gives different accuracy scores when evaluating the model on the test data. 100% on windows and 93% on mac OS. Both machines run python 3.7.3 64-bit.

The data is split using `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` with 0.8 for training and 0.2 for testing, `random_state` is 1. Data and labels are properly normalised and adjusted to fit into the CNN. Various numbers for `steps_per_epoch`, `batch_size` and `epoch` have been tried.

I have tried using both `np.random.seed` and `tensorflow.set_random_seed`, generating 100% accuracy on the test data using `seed(1)` on PC, however the same seed on the other machine still yields a different accuracy score.

Here is the CNN architecture along with the method call for creating additional images. The following code yields an accuracy of 100% on one machine and 93.33% on the other.

```py
seed(185)
set_random_seed(185)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64), validation_data=(X_test,y_test),steps_per_epoch= 30, epochs=10)

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

**EDIT**
So after more research I've discovered that using different hardware, specifically different graphics cards, will result in varying accuracies.
Saving the trained model and using that to evalute data on different machines is the ideal solution.

Comment: Did you train the models on different machines?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Yes, training the model and then evaluating is what yields different results

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Question Section, for the benefit of the community.

Using different hardware, specifically different graphics cards will result in varying accuracies though we use same seeds, code and dataset. `Saving the trained model and using that to evaluate data` on different machines is the ideal solution.